# Infinitive usage as an adjective

Tags: infinitives, infinitive-clauses, infinitive-phrases

I'm studying infinitives being a verbal that can function as noun, adjective, or adverb.

I'm somewhat confused that the following sentences are correct. If so, what is difference between them? If I had some tasks, I would prefer to go with second one.

- I have some tasks to do.
- I have some tasks to be done.

Comment: I would avoid the term "verbal". They are not adjectives, but clauses. "To do / to be done" are interrogative infinitival clauses functioning as complement of "tasks". The latter is passive. They have a deontic meaning, as if the modal auxiliary "should" was included. The meaning is "I have some tasks I should do / that should be done".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some tasks to do, then it’s you who has to do them. If you have some tasks to be done, then anyone can do them. You might say “I have some tasks to be done. Alice, you can do this one. Bob, this one is for you.”